# Draw effect XNA with multiple texture

Tags: c#, xna, hlsl

In Xna I would like to draw my model with a custom effect.. SO I would like to get the textures from the mesh.

```html
 foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
            {

                foreach (ModelMeshPart part in mesh.MeshParts)
                {
                    

                    effect.Parameters["World"].SetValue(World );
                    effect.Parameters["View"].SetValue(View);
                    effect.Parameters["Projection"].SetValue(Projection);
                    effect.Parameters["TextureEnabled"].SetValue(true);

                    
                    
                    var basicEffect = part.Effect as BasicEffect;
                    if (basicEffect != null)
                    {
                        Texture2D texName = basicEffect.Texture;
                        effect.Parameters["Texture"].SetValue(texName);

                    }

                    part.Effect = effect;

                }
                mesh.Draw();

            }
```

the model is black if I run this code.. but if I  remove the if (basicEffect != null) it appears correctly for 1 fram but then a Null exception appears.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to get it right by changing the code to that:

```html
        Texture2D[] texts =  new Texture2D[40000];
        bool bol = true;
        public void DrawModel( camera cam)
        {

           

            int i = 0;
            foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
            {

                foreach (ModelMeshPart part in mesh.MeshParts)
                {
                    effect.Parameters["World"].SetValue(World );
                    effect.Parameters["View"].SetValue(View);
                    effect.Parameters["Projection"].SetValue(Projection);
                    effect.Parameters["TextureEnabled"].SetValue(true);


                    
                    var basicEffect = part.Effect as BasicEffect;
                    if (bol && basicEffect != null)
                    {
                        texts[i] = basicEffect.Texture;
                    }

                    
                    effect.Parameters["Texture"].SetValue(texts[i]);
                    i++;

                    part.Effect = effect;
                }
                mesh.Draw();

            }
            bol = false;
        }
```